# Duplicate rows, different PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have this query :

```
SELECT pih.PID, piv.TSV, piv.Variable_ID, piv.Value_ID, piv.Manual_Value
FROM Process_Instance_Value AS piv
INNER JOIN Process_Instance_History AS pih ON piv.PID = pih.PID
WHERE piv.Variable_ID IN ( SELECT Variable_ID 
                           FROM someTable 
                           WHERE Transition_ID = @someValue) 
AND piv.PID = @someValue
```

I get this :

[image]

My problem is that those rows are duplicate for the use I want them at this point.
Is it possible to only get rows on DISTINCT TSV? Or something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Which pih.PID would you like to retrieve then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      pih.PID, 
      piv.TSV, 
      piv.Variable_ID, 
      piv.Value_ID, 
      piv.Manual_Value,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY piv.TSV ORDER BY pih.PID) rownum
    FROM Process_Instance_Value AS piv
    INNER JOIN Process_Instance_History AS pih ON piv.PID = pih.PID
    WHERE piv.Variable_ID IN ( SELECT Variable_ID 
                               FROM someTable 
                               WHERE Transition_ID = @someValue) 
    AND piv.PID = @someValue
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

**Note that:** This will return the minimum `pih.PID` for each distinct `piv.TSV` if you want the max, just use `ORDER BY pih.PID DESC` instead.

**How does this work:**

The ranking function [**`ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) will give a ranking number for each group that has the same column listed in the `PARTITION BY`, in our case `piv.TSV`, this ranking number will be ordered, for each group, according to the `ORDER BY` clause defined inside the `OVER` clause, in our case `ORDER BY pih.PID`. I used a [**CTE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of using subquery.

Then the I used `WHERE rownum = 1`, since the ranking number `rownum` was given for each group of records that has the same `piv.TSV` ranked in descendent order, then the record with `rownum = 1` will be the record with the minimum `pih.PID`(think about it).

You can however, get the same result using an inner join with a `GROUP BY` like so:

```
    SELECT 
      pih.PID, 
      piv.TSV, 
      piv.Variable_ID, 
      piv.Value_ID, 
      piv.Manual_Value
    FROM Process_Instance_Value AS piv
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
          TSV, MIN(PID) MinPID
        FROM Process_Instance_Value 
        GROUP BY TSV
    ) piv2 ON piv.PID = piv2.MinPID
    INNER JOIN Process_Instance_History AS pih ON piv.PID = pih.PID
    WHERE piv.Variable_ID IN ( SELECT Variable_ID 
                               FROM someTable 
                               WHERE Transition_ID = @someValue) 
    AND piv.PID = @someValue
```

Comment: Won't the "where rownum = 1" ensure you only get 1 row...though matter how many distinct piv.TSV's?

Comment: @Gerrat One row per `TSV`, that's what the `PARTITION BY` is doing.

Comment: @hermann - Sorry, I added an explanation. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

do you want

```
SELECT pih.PID,  piv.Variable_ID, piv.Value_ID, piv.Manual_Value
FROM Process_Instance_Value AS piv
INNER JOIN Process_Instance_History AS pih ON piv.PID = pih.PID
WHERE piv.Variable_ID IN ( SELECT Variable_ID 
                           FROM someTable 
                           WHERE Transition_ID = @someValue) 
AND piv.PID = @someValue
group by
pih.PID,  piv.Variable_ID, piv.Value_ID, piv.Manual_Value
```